# How can I have Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

```
    public interface IOperationResult
    {
        bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ICreateCommandOperationResult<T?> : IOperationResult
    {
        public T? InsertedId { get; set; }
    }
```

When I insert a record in database, I want to return inserted record's Id.
But sometimes there are exceptions that in this case I need to send `null` in `InsertedId`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Make your `ICreateCommandOperationResult` generic on `T` (i.e., `ICreateCommandOperationResult<T>`), constrain `T` to a `struct` and then use `T?` as the type of `InsertedId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the `where T: struct` [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) (or `class` if you are using C# 8 and need a [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#nullable-reference-types)) and replace `T?` with just `T` in `ICreateCommandOperationResult` interface.

```cs
public interface ICreateCommandOperationResult<T> : IOperationResult
    where T : struct //where T : class
{
    public T? InsertedId { get; set; }
}
```

The example of implementation

```cs
public class Test : ICreateCommandOperationResult<int>
{
    public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int? InsertedId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The compiler was happy about `struct` but not about class

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, I've pointed it in aswer, that it's valid in C#8 in case of using nullable reference types

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - Yes, Pavel, my comment was directed at Hamid. He may not have understood that.